# What kind of command is "sudo", "su", or "torify"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

I know what they do. I was just wondering what kind of command are they. How can you make one using shell scripting.
For example, command like:

```
ignoreError ls /Home/
ignoreError mkdir /Home/
ignoreError cat
ignoreError randomcommand
```

Hope you get the idea

Comment: They run another command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to do it in a shell script is with the `"$@"` construct.

`"$@"` expands to a quoted list of all of the arguments you passed to your shell script.  `$1` would be the command you want your shell script to run, and `$2` `$3` etc are the arguments to **that** command.

The only example I have is from cygwin.  Cygwin does not have `sudo`, but I have this script that emulates it:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
cygstart --action=runas "$@"
```

So when I run a command like

```
$ sudo ls -l
```

my `sudo` script does whatever it needs to do (`cygstart --action=runas`) and calls the `ls` command with the `-l` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
"$@"
```

Call it, for example, `run`, make it runnable `chmod u+x run`, and try it:

```
$ run ls -l #or ./run ls -l
...
  output of ls
...
```

The idea is that the script takes the parameters specified on the command line and use them as a (sub)command... Modify the script this way:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Trying to run $*"
"$@"
```

and you will see.

Comment: That's true, but OP doesn't request such advanced things, he just wanted to know how to make a script able to launch another command. These are advanced shell considerations.